# Flip DetailsViewController

Tags: iphone, sdk

I would like to create a second view for DetailsViewController. The plan is to have the info button on DetailsViewController and when user click on it, it will flip DetailsView to another view. Just wondering if this is even possible to do it or not. I search everywhere and was not able to find solutions. 
Please help and thanks in advance.

P.S. The app is tab bar application

Answer (score 0):

```
Instead of Navigation you can use your own class.

[UIView beginAnimations:@"animation" context:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController: yourviewcontroller animated:NO]; 
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO]; 
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: I'm not using storyboards (my app is made for older version of iOS). The question is can I have two views on DetailsViewController so I have main view and info view if you will.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using storyboards you could do this very easily using a segue, simply set its style to modal and its transition to "Flip Horizontal".